# Getting error No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I am using Npgsql ADO dot net connector to communicate to postgresql from C# code.

Function is available in the postgresql DB, also I am able to execute it from pgadmin tool but unable to call it from c# code.

getting error

> 42883: function
>   public.insert_json_array_to_test_method_temp(p_input_test_name =>
>   text, p_input_test_type_xref => text, p_input_unit_Attribute => text)
>   does not exist"}
>
> error hint - No function matches the given name and argument types.
>   You might need to add explicit type casts.

Below is the C# code

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(_connStr);               
conn.Open();               
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("public.insert_json_array_to_test_method_temp", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("p_input_test_name", NpgsqlDbType.Text) { Value = testmethod });
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("p_input_test_type_xref", NpgsqlDbType.Text) { Value = testtypexref });
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("p_input_unit_Attribute", NpgsqlDbType.Text) { Value = unitattributes });

NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   while (dr.Read())
            {

            }         conn.Close();
```

Below is the function header section

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
   public.insert_json_array_to_test_method_temp(p_input_test_name 
   text,p_input_test_type_xref text,p_input_unit_attribute text)
   RETURNS text
   LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

     COST 100
VOLATILE 
 AS $BODY$  
 DECLARE res Text;

BEGIN

--some logic with parameters

res:= public."InsertTestNames"();

 Return 'done';

 END;

 $BODY$;
```

Can any one please help what is the problem here ?

Comment: That's really not how you create a postgresql function. I would suggest to check the manual - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html Also, a function is expected to return data or perform any operation. What does your function do? This looks more of a create table statement to me.

Comment: Georgi Raychev  i have not pasted the complete function code here,function is having return type body etc.also i am able to call this method from pgadmin tool

Comment: Do you need the public when you setup the command?

Comment: have tried without public also.

Comment: There's a problem with your postgresql function, which you are not showing to us. You can't expect much help on this. Probably you are feeding it with wrong data type, but who knows...

Comment: @Georgi Raychev I have added funcation, could you please check now ?

Answer (score 2):

I changed the way I was creating the parameters and was casting it - it's now working.

```
var parameter1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
parameter1.ParameterName = "parameter_name";
parameter1.NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlDbType.Text;
parameter1.Value = parameter_value;
cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter1);
```